# Monitoring Logged In Users in MS Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form on a tab that I use to monitor users who are logged in to my application.

[image]

The table is called USysRollCall (prefixed with USys to automatically make it invisible as a system table if access is gained to the navigation pane)

Only 3 fields are necessary:  UserName (string) , As_of (date) and Logged_In (boolean)

All new users are automatically added to the UsysRollCall table

A "frm_Invisible" form launches with my main form and remains in the background.  On the load and unload event of this form, I call the following routine like this:

Upon logging in:   UserActive(AcquireUser, True)

Upon Logging Out   UserActive(AcquireUser, False)

```
Public Sub UserActive(strUserName As String, bTrueFalse)

If bTrueFalse = True Then

    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE USysRollCall SET Logged_In =-1, As_of=#" & Now & "# WHERE UserName='" & strUserName & "';"

Else
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE USysRollCall SET Logged_In =0, As_of=#" & Now & "# WHERE UserName='" & strUserName & "';"

End If


End Sub
```

'The following function can be used any time to get the username.  It also serves a dual purpose of automatically taking necessary actions to add a new username to the user table if it is called and a username is not in the table.  (not provided for this example)

```
Public Function AcquireUser() As String
'Returns the username
'but checks to see if it is in the table - if not... it adds it to the table as the lowest security level



Dim strUserName As String

strUserName = GetUserName



If Len(CheckUser(strUserName)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Will be adding " & strUserName & " to the database"

    AddUser (strUserName)
    AcquireUser = strUserName
    'MsgBox GreetUser(strUSERNAME), vbInformation, "Welcome"

Else
    AcquireUser = strUserName

End If

End Function
```

I can verify that when I login and check the backend table, UsysRollCall I see a check in the Logged_In box.  I can also verify that no matter how I close the database i.e. appropriately by using my quit button - or even just using the close X in the top right, that it still effectively logs me out.

I cannot verify what causes people to remain "Logged_In"
Is there a piece I am missing?

Comment: Gee, perhaps access is crashing? Is there some timer event active? As you note, you can't re=produce this on your own. any possible that users hold down shift key during startup and by-pass your startup code?

Comment: I have the shift key disabled aa well as the menus.  There must be some kind of a sweeping action to clean it out to verify if people are actually logged in.

Comment: What happens when a user loses the network connection? I had similar problems when ppl worked with wifi and the signal was sometimes so bad that it lost the connection.